Button is taking focus even when TabStop is set to false
On a Form I have 2 Labels and a Button.
In one of these Labels my game is played, but I am having an issue: the player plays this game using their 'WASD' and arrow keys; when the player uses their arrow keys for the first time, the focus is put on the Button and the user can no longer use their arrow keys.
This is obvious as the blue outline appears around the Button immediately after pressing an arrow key.
Is there a way I can prevent this from happening? While still having the Button remain clickable with the players' mouse? Although it wouldn't be difficult at all, I would like to avoid having to rebind the controls.
I have tried changing the TabStop property of the Button to false, changing the order of the TabIndex unsurprisingly didn't fix the problem either.
I know it is the Button that is causing the issue, as the Button is really the only interactable object (in the traditional sense?) on my Form, is it naive to say that it isn't necessary for a windows Form to have something in focus at all times.

Another approach would be to remove the button and use hotkey (similar to handling arrow keys) to perform its action.

A Button Control is selectable by default.
If it's the only Control on a Form, that's UI element that is going to become the ActiveControl and receive focus.
If you have set KeyPreview = true in your Form, and you're handling PreviewKeyDown, you are going to get a notification on the first input key, then the only focusable Control (your Button) becomes the ActiveControl.
In this case, navigation keys (e.g., Cursor keys), interaction keys (e.g., Space Bar) and mnemonics are processed, other keys are discarded, your Form won't receive the related messages (at least not WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP).
In cases when you don't want your Button Controls to eat the key presses (as a simplified description of the underlying events), or steal the focus from other Controls (e.g., when used as the keys of a virtual Keyboard), I usually replace the standard Button with a custom one.
This custom Button just sets a Style that prevents it from taking Focus, while it maintains all other functionality:
public class ButtonNoFocus : Button {
    public ButtonNoFocus() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}

If you add this class to the Project (you can add it to the Form itself), then replace, in the Form's Designer file, all instances of Type Button with ButtonNoFocus, you get your PreviewKeyDown handler working again

YES! This fixed my issue exactly! And was remarkably easy to implement. Thank you so much!
